How to enable a 86 Keys ANSI Layout keyboard
I bought an Attack Shark K86 keyboard. It is in ISO format with 86 keys as shown in the image below:
attack Shark K86
However, I could not find any regionalization settings available on the keyboard settings screen in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. Is there any way to install it? Which keyboard mode should I use?
